# How to replicate ASP.NET MVC's RenderAction in Nancy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nancy

I'm considering porting an existing ASP.NET MVC3 application onto Nancy.

The application currently makes heavy use of the html helper extension RenderAction.

I can't work out how to replicate this behaviour in Nancy.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box - while it's possible, it's also going to be a reasonable amount of work and will require you knowing quite a bit about Nancy's guts to implement. We support rendering partials, but not rerunning the whole request stack (which is essentially what RenderAction does).

Comment: Thanks for this.  It seems that I'm swimming against the current with this approach.  I'll try to find an alternative mechanism to build my modular pages.